# How to resolve SpringBoot 405 Method Not Allowed Error?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am expecting to receive the message "Works" on Postman (used for temporary testing until I implement the frontend and forms using HTML and CSS) when I type in the URL "http://localhost:8080/registration". This should be happening based on the code posted below. Instead, I receive the 405 Method Not Allowed Error.

WebSecurityConfig class
package com.example.finalVersionBookProject.security.config;

```
import com.example.finalVersionBookProject.appuser.AppUserService;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import       org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import  org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private final AppUserService appUserService;
private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
public WebSecurityConfig(AppUserService appUserService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
this.appUserService = appUserService;
this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}
```

Registration class

```
    package com.example.finalVersionBookProject.registration;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(path = "/registration")
    public class Registration {
    private RegistrationService registrationService;

    @PostMapping()
    public String register(@RequestBody RegistrationRequest request) {
    return registrationService.register(request);
    }

    }

Registration Service Class
```

```
package com.example.finalVersionBookProject.registration;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class RegistrationService {
public String register(RegistrationRequest request) {
return "works";
}
}
```

```
I have tried replacing RestController with Controller, changing some of the annotations, both with no success. I tried using the IntelliJ debugger to resolve the issue, but it did not provide any new information that was helpful in solving the problem. I am expecting the message "Works" to be outputted to Postman, but I get the 405 Error.
```

Comment: Can you please share curl request?

Answer (score -1):

When you type in URL `http://localhost:8080/registration` in Postman, what method did you use? I suspect you are using `GET` whilst your controller has a `@PostMapping` which support `POST` method.

You can try to use `@GetMapping` instead.

Comment: I am using a post request from Postman, not a get request. I don't think that is an issue.